# Selenium find element error, but same code with js can work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

use the python execute can find the element bottom and click, it works:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName(\"g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label\")[0].click()")
```

but with the similar code, the python code can not work:

```
element_install_bottom=driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value=r'g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label')
```

and throw the exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label"]"}
```

and have try by.ID, by.ClassName; but always throw the exception.

the whole code as below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

```
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

USER_DATA_PATH = r"D:\Chrome\User Data 3"
option.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={USER_DATA_PATH}')
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])

print(option.arguments)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

extension_url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=zh-CN"
driver.get(extension_url)
time.sleep(60)


element_install_bottom=driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value=r'g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label')
print(element_install_bottom)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing that exception as there is no element with that ID, that value is it's class.

Python:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label")
```

or:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "g-c-R  webstore-test-button-label")
```